# How can I open external link in angular cli?

Tags: angular

How can I open an external link in a page html in angular cli project? I want external link opened inside a page html of a component.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe try an iframe ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `<a href="google.com" target="_blank">Click me!</a>`?

Comment: No. The first suggestion is good. But with Iframe I obtain  "Refused to display 'link' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."

Comment: Oh, I understood. You could just access the DOM directly with document.getElementById('iframe').innerHTML = "<iframe src='${data}'></iframe>", or use Renderer2 class to access the parent element with @ViewChild('element') el:ElementRef.